# Android Error Running App

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Before I test a project, everything is fine. But then, when I click the run button, I get an error:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Jim\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

In the console, I get this:

Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]

```
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72220Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42220Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets
:app:generateDebugResValues
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 17.327 secs
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72220Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42220Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"res\\drawable-mdpi-v4\\private.png:0: error:     invalid symbol: \u0027private\u0027","position":{},"original":"res\\drawable-    mdpi-v4\\private.png:0: error: invalid symbol: \u0027private\u0027"}


FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:         org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Jim\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 5.219 secs

I use Android Studio.This is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.bob.app"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
}
```

Then, when I use R, I get an error: Cannot resolve symbol R

but I just use setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

How can I solve this error?

Comment: try changing your buildToolsVersion to "21.0.1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I actually had an image that wasn't working. I deleted the image and the program ran.

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"res\\drawable-mdpi-v4\\private.png:0: error:     invalid symbol: \u0027private\u0027","position":{},"original":"res\\drawable-    mdpi-v4\\private.png:0: error: invalid symbol: \u0027private\u0027"}
```

private.png was an image. It had nothing to do with my gradle files or any code.